# Unable to translate Unicode character '\uDA22'

Tags: c#

Hi im retrieving registry data and whilst outputting to a file i came across this. Im not 100% sure what it is, i would guess it is a registry value i captured. Is there any easy way i can eliminate this problem, preferable without deleting the data?

Answer (score 1):

\uDA22 is part of a [surrogate pair](http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php?block=91) and should not appear on its own. If it does, your data is corrupted. Surrogate pairs are used only for rather exotic characters outside the basic multilingual plane. It seems a bit strange to find them in the registry, unless you're dealing with Chinese-language applications.

What encoding are you using to write the file? The error occurs either because your input contains corrupted UTF-16 data (though I suspect that the error message would be different then) or because the encoding you're using cannot represent those characters, which would be true for the default encoding on an English-language Windows. The easiest fix would be to use UTF-8 as encoding.